# which one is better

Tags: seo, search-engines, ranking

I don't know whether I land to exact forum site or not! if anyone knows the answer please provide

Hello community

My question is most of the domains on the first page has non-WWW URL thereby If I consider High domain authoritative sites including

Moz and ahref or even webmasters.stackexchange : the site URL is without www

on the contrary, when I take Google it has www

It just confused me, could anyone solve my issue that which one is better for SEO?

Comment: WWW or not does not matter. It is just a personal choice. One does not perform better the the other. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the thing.

**www is actually a subdomain** and that is why it is considered 2 different sites

For instance, **shop.example.com is not the same as example.com/shop**

I think the wisest approach is make sure your sites are connected and are getting credit as one site.

What I normally do is put a **redirect** for a user **typing www to the non-www** site or vice versa, if the client has a preference.

If you look at Google, **you can not visit non-www.Google.com, it will redirect you to a www version.**

So even Google is using the same redirect principle.

I hope that helps and makes sense.

Comment: but my concern is not redirecting but website ranking. I observed the google result page has 6 non www sites out of 10, so would like to know, whether this http non www domain will get any additional ranking boost or what?

Comment: It will make no difference whatsoever if that is the only factor. What you don't want is 2 sites, one www and one non-www and them not being associated.  The result would be 2 different sites with duplicate content and a non accurate visitor total, which that by itself will make a big difference in SEO.